# How to use jsonpath in ballerina?

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I was trying to process some json data. I would like to know whether it is possible to use jsonPath in ballerina 0.990.2? Something similar to `$..temperature[?(@.celcius<25)]`

Answer (score 1):

Ballerina does not support the JSON path spec. However, it supports a field-based-access and index-based-access syntax for JSON, where you can access fields of JSON-objects and elements of JSON-arrays similar to that of JSON path.

eg:

```
json j = ...;
string name = j.a.b[3].c;
```

Not all the features of JSON paths such as wildcards, filters, etc. are supported yet.